# проблемы с collapse, не получается навигацию позиционировать по центру, так же не выводится кнопочная иконка, хотя все для нее подключено и прописано

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-navbar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">о процедуре</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">отзывы</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">центр обучения</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">контакты</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а бутстрап css подключили?

Comment: спасибо я разобрался, вернее не разобрался, но сделал по другому, кнопку подставил через font awesome. Да у меня все подключено